# Connection to a Noontec N5 NAS problem

Tags: samba, nas, smb

I can't seem to connect to my Noontec N5 NAS no matter what I try. Windows has no issues and it's apparently possible.

I have searched the interwebs and found nothing about this. Has anyone else had any issues?

Comment: Please post the relevant error messages you see, your OS, version and what you already tried.

Comment: No error, it just keeps asking for login details over and over. It works fine is Win 7 or 8. I'm trying to connect using Lubuntu PCManFM. Connecting using smb://noontec-n5/ or smb://user@noontec-n5 doesn't work. I have no problem connecting to my other NAS which is a DNS-320L. My OS is Lubuntu 14.04 LTS and fully updated. Noontec-N5 firmware: NAS-1Bay-N5_J1.05A_L1.04T_Ver2.35_USB2.0 Any ideas?

Comment: Same Noontec N5 problem here, I've tried running the command: 'smbclient //NAS-NoontecN5/music -U Jeremy -W WORKGROUP', but I get 'session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE'. Tried with and without specifying the workgroup, and prefixing the host name 'NAS-NoontecN5' before the username. The same share authenticates and works just fine if connecting from Windows or Android.

Comment: @navhaxs and OP: see [my self-answered question](http://askubuntu.com/a/582928/19501) on this. Basically, you need to force `NTLM` auth, not `NTLMv2`.